# Android: Changing "ViewPager" animation from Fragment to Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentmanager

I am having an application with few fragments. I am using `ViewPager` and I have an expectation of providing a different animation for `ViewPager` transactions. Below is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int counterNumber=-1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter2(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                    counterNumber=0;
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 1) {
                    counterNumber=1;
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 2) {
                    counterNumber=2;
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 3) {
                    counterNumber=3;
                    return true;
                }

                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 4) {
                    counterNumber=4;
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });

        viewPager.setPageTransformer(false, new ViewPager.PageTransformer() {
            @Override
            public void transformPage(View page, float position) {

                page.setRotation(position*-100);

            }
        });

    }

    private class MyPagerAdapter2 extends FragmentPagerAdapter {


        public MyPagerAdapter2(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos) {

                case 0: counterNumber=0; return FirstFragment1.newInstance("FirstFragment_1");
                case 1: counterNumber=1;return SecondFragment1.newInstance("SecondFragment_1");
                case 2: counterNumber=2;return ThirdFragment1.newInstance("ThirdFragment_1");
                case 3: counterNumber=3;return FourthFragment1.newInstance("FourthFragment_1");
                case 4: counterNumber=4;return FifthFragment1.newInstance("FifthFragment_1");
                default: return FirstFragment1.newInstance("DefaultFragment_1");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }
    }

    public void setCurrentItem(int which) {
        if(viewPager != null && which >= 0 && which <= 4) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(which);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I do not need same animation to all the screens. However I only want this custom animation in some cases, like when you are coming back from 4th screen into 3rd screen. Or else when a button is called in 3rd screen which is instructed to navigate back to 1st screen.

To do this, can I get find the called Fragment (let's say `viewPager.setCurrentItem(4)` is called) and make the animation available only to that fragment?

Or else even better, is there a way for me to individually define/change the animation? Like in third Fragment when "Go to Fragment 2" button is pressed - display one animation, in first fragment when "Go to Fragment 10" is pressed, display one animation?

Anyway whatever the way I select, the `ViewPager` cannot be removed because I have already applied it largely in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you

```
   if (position == 1) {
                    viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());
                } else {
                    viewPager.setPageTransformer(true, null);
                }
```

add this code into viewPager onPageChangeListener

Comment: Thanks. However it seems not working well. Seems when we come back the animation get stuck in the middle.